# How to implement interoperation between XAML and a DirectX swap chain with C++/WinRT

Tags: xaml, c++-winrt, directx-12

Microsoft Documentation provides the code to implement interoperation between XAML and a DirectX swap chain with C++ [1]:

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ISwapChainPanelNative>   m_swapChainNative;
// ...
IInspectable* panelInspectable = (IInspectable*) reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(swapChainPanel);
panelInspectable->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ISwapChainPanelNative), (void **)&m_swapChainNative);
```

However, I was not able to figure out how I should implement this with C++/WinRT.

When using this code, I get the following error message :

" [...] 'reinterpret_cast': cannot convert from 'winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SwapChainPanel' to 'IInspectable *' "

I'm using DirectX12, Visual Studio 2017.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop/nn-windows-ui-xaml-media-dxinterop-iswapchainpanelnative

Comment: As for the rest of my code, I started from one side with a blank template for C++/WinRT application and I took the rendering pipeline entirely from [2]. 
I have not other build issue apart from the code that should link XAML and DirectX. 

[2]: https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/UWPSamples/IntroGraphics/SimpleTriangleCppWinRT_UWP12

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that WRL documentation is using `reinterpret_cast`. C++/WinRT makes this pretty simple:

```
winrt::com_ptr<ISwapChainswapChainNative> m_swapChainNative;
// ...
swapChainNative = swapChainPanel.as<ISwapChainPanelNative>();
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks; I still have problems. Apparently, to see the ISwapChainswapChainNative interface, it needs "#include <windows.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h>" as considered in [3], found after googling about your code. Then, I get this error: "binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'winrt::com_ptr<T>' " referring to "swapChainNative = swapChainPanel.as<ISwapChainPanelNative>();" ; I have swapChainPanel defined as: SwapChainPanel swapChainPanel. 

[3]: <https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/67>

Comment: I literally just compiled this successfully against the 17763 SDK version of cppwinrt:

``` 

#include <windows.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "WindowsApp.lib")

using namespace winrt;

int main()
{
    winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SwapChainPanel swapChainPanel{ nullptr };
    // ...
    winrt::com_ptr<ISwapChainPanelNative> m_swapChainNative;
    m_swapChainNative = swapChainPanel.as<ISwapChainPanelNative>();

}
```

Comment: Many Thanks Ryan, by including the mentioned files I can see that the interoperation related code builds correctly. Adding "m_swapChainNative->SetSwapChain(swapChain);" makes everything working, too.